# Data imported from Excel not appended in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Trying to import data from an Excel sheet and append to an Access table.  It reads the first value and appends it, but the second value is not interpreted as data, for some reason.

I assume it is a format issue for the data4 variable, or the way it is called in the qs line.  Any help?

```
    Public Sub Import2(FileName As Variant)
    Dim wb As Object, ws As Object
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    Dim qs As String

    Dim oConn As Object
    Set oConn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
    oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Robert\desktop\testMAF.xlsm; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML; hdr=no" & ";"

    'Open workbook specified in previous procedure and import data from specified cells
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
            Set ws = wb.worksheets("For Export")
            data1 = ws.cells(2, 1)
            Data2 = ws.cells(2, 2)
            Data3 = ws.cells(2, 3)
            Data4 = ws.cells(2, 4)
            'Continues to ...Data62 = ws.cells(2 , 62)


    'The following commented code works, entering a date into the Formdate field on the MAF table
    'qs = "INSERT INTO MAF (FormDate) VALUES (#" & data1 & "#)"

    'However, when I expanded it to include the second field (below)it will not enter the value into the table.
    'The locals window shows qs=...Values(#1/4/2010#,Postflight) which is what I want to append
    'but when qs is executed, I am prompted, "Enter Parameter Value for Postflight"


    qs = "INSERT INTO MAF (FormDate,SN) VALUES (#" & data1 & "#," & Data4 & ")"

    DoCmd.RunSQL (qs)


    End Sub
```

Comment: not sure of your Access version but why not just use [TransferSpreadsheet Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)? Otherwise, you will need to Dimension all the `Data` variables to the exact data type of each field in Access. Getting data types between Excel and Access is hairy and must be done with caution, otherwise blow-ups occur. I find `TransferSpreadsheet` much easier, even if I have to format excel columns first (through code, I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes before and after the text value *"Postflight"* (which is the value contained in the `Data4` variable) ...

```vb
qs = "INSERT INTO MAF (FormDate,SN) VALUES (#" & data1 & "#,'" & Data4 & "')"
                                                            ^             ^
```

You can make trouble-shooting easier if you use a variable to hold the `INSERT` statement ...

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO MAF (FormDate,SN) VALUES (#" & data1 & "#,'" & Data4 & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

But quote issues would be less of a pain if you switch to a parameter query for your `INSERT` or if you use `DAO.Recordset.AddNew` to add the row to the `MAF` table.

Here is a `Recordset` example (untested) ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MAF", dbAppendOnly)
With rs
    .AddNew
    !FormatDate.Value = data1
    !SN.Value = Data4
    .Update
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  My next project is to learn about recordsets, for that exact reason.  I am figuring this stuff out one tiny step at a time!

Comment: You're welcome.  I added a brief recordset example ... you don't need to bother about quotes for string values or `#` delimiters for date/time values.

Comment: Also, if you can use `TransferSpreadsheet` as Scott suggested, you would need less code to import the Excel data.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is almost certainly in Excel.  Excel will allow you to enter any kind of data (text, numbers, dates, etc.) all in the same column.  Access prevents this by requiring you to define a Data Type.  Clean up the data in Excel.  Also, consider using one of these methods to move your data from Excel to Access.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportado

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportdao